# ejs template engine, extend parent to form a decent design pattern

Tags: node.js, twig, template-engine, ejs

With the templating system [twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/extends.html) you can extend a parent template with the extends function.

I am just starting out with node and having a go with the ejs template engine but cannot find similar functionality. Does anyone know if this is possible with ejs, and if not is there a js tpl engine that can extend a parent?

I want to build a simple tpl structure eg:

```
<pagelayout.ejs>
  <publicHeadScripts.ejs />
  <pageBodyBlock>
  <publicFooter.ejs />
</pagelayout.ejs>
```

But multiple routes will require this tpl structue and i don't want to have to include all the above files all the time. EG  /coolpage  would route to  but this itself would be injected into the above "pageBodyBlock".

Thanks in advance,
John

Comment: http://bits.shutterstock.com/2013/03/07/mustache-vs-swig-templating-shootout/  Swig seeems to be the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, there is a port of twig... it goes by the name of swig :)

http://paularmstrong.github.io/swig/

It is awesome!

Comment: link seems to be broken